# Unexpected token, expected "..." react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to add a loading spinner for a `TouchableOpacity` in React by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgDObZGhQuw) tutorial

When I'm trying to add

```
{loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}
```

to the TouchableOpacity I'm getting:

> Unexpected token, expected "..."

I tried adding ... before the loading but it won't show the spinner when I press the button and I can't figure out why.

Here is the full code:

```
class App extends Component {
state = {
    loading: false
}
    <View style={{padding: 15}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
      {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}
      style={styles.button}
      disabled={loading}
      onPress={() => this.postroom(155)}  
      >
      <Text style={{color: "white" , fontSize: hp('3%')}}>Post room</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

Updated:
For anyone looking for why I didn't see the icon, I didn't import import "font-awesome.min.css"

Comment: What happens if you do `{true && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}`? Does the spin show? If yes, it means loading is not set to `true` when it should

Comment: @Magofoco it doesn't show, but I have to do "...true" instead of "true" it might be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the syntax itself, you cannot add `{ /* your code */ }` into the component's tag as you have tried in your example.

Try as the following instead:

```
{loading ?
   <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> :
   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                     disabled={loading}
                     onPress={() => this.postroom(155)} >
         <Text style={{color: "white" , fontSize: hp('3%')}}>Post room</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

Or you can add into the text component also as:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                  disabled={loading}
                  onPress={() => this.postroom(155)} >
     <Text style={{color: "white" , fontSize: hp('3%')}}>
        {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}
        Post room
     </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I tried the second option, I don't get any errors so that's nice but still, when I click the button I can't see the spinner in the button :/

Comment: Have you tried render only `<i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>` if that's showing anything alone? Maybe there is an issue with not loaded font awesome, or something else. Or also you can try adding instead of the icon, just a text as `<span>Loading...</span>` for testing purposes.

Comment: you're right I tried to render <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> and I can't see anything hmm, I'll look up what could it be, anyway you solved my problem.

Comment: @yarinCohen Awesome, happy to help!